# System.TypeException: "emailSimple" isn't a valid action type

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage, invocable-method

I am trying to use an standard Invocable Action "Send Email" from my apex code with the following snippet:

```
Invocable.Action action = Invocable.Action.createStandardAction('emailSimple');
action.setInvocationParameter('emailAddresses', o.Quote.ShippingEmail__c);    
action.setInvocationParameter('logEmailOnSend', true);
action.setInvocationParameter('relatedRecordId', o.Id);
....
```

However, when I test it, I am getting the following issue: **System.TypeException: "emailSimple" isn't a valid action type.**

How am I supposed to use it then?

In the documentation example here, they are using the "chatterPost" action: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_invocableaction_class.htm&release=240&type=5

Chatter Post action documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_post_to_chatter.htm

Send email action documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_email_simple.htm

Comment: [unofficialsf mentions that only a subset of standard actions are available](https://unofficialsf.com/calling-invocable-actions-from-apex/), but I can't find any supporting documentation for that. That said, it wouldn't surprise me if Salesforce released this feature in a "half-baked" state (a pox on MVP culture, I say).

Comment: I would also like to know where these subset comes from, but at least I know It was not me doing anything wrong. Thanks